# Javascript - get 1 oldest date from array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array with this format. I just want to pull the 1 oldest date.

This is value in array looks like:

## Array:

creationDate = ['Wed Feb 13 21:14:55 GMT 2019','Wed Feb 13 21:19:42 GMT 2019','Wed Feb 13 21:28:29 GMT 2019','Wed Feb 13 21:31:04 GMT 2019'];

This is my code:

## Code:

```
        // this below code is not working as expected   
        if(creationDate){
            var orderedDates = creationDate.sort(function(a,b){
                return Date.parse(a) > Date.parse(b);
            }); 
        }
```

## Expected Result:

Wed Feb 13 21:14:55 GMT 2019

Comment: Try using `Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b)` (or switch a and b to sort in the opposite order). The compare function expects a number to be returned rather than a boolean. Check rules for thee compare function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to return a number, not a Boolean (so use `-` not `>`):

```js
var creationDate = ['Wed Feb 13 21:14:55 GMT 2019', 'Wed Feb 13 21:19:42 GMT 2019', 'Wed Feb 13 21:28:29 GMT 2019', 'Wed Feb 13 21:31:04 GMT 2019', 'Wed Feb 13 21:33:04 GMT 2019'];
var orderedDates = creationDate.sort(function(a, b) {
  return Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b);
});
console.log(orderedDates[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array.reduce()` and on each iteration compare the dates and take the oldest:

```js
const creationDate = ['Wed Feb 13 21:14:55 GMT 2019','Wed Feb 13 21:19:42 GMT 2019','Wed Feb 13 21:28:29 GMT 2019','Wed Feb 13 21:31:04 GMT 2019'];

const oldest = creationDate.reduce((c, n) => 
  Date.parse(n) < Date.parse(c) ? n : c
);

console.log(oldest);
```

Comment: Better than sorting as it doesn't mutate the original array like sort does.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(creationDates){
  return creationDates.sort()[0]
}
```